# Singular or plural form of a noun

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> The A and B **group(s)** were comprised of 100 and 150 individuals.

In this sentence, which of singular or plural form should I choose?
Or does it make sense if both are used?

Thank you for your answer in advance. :)

Comment: The A and B groups comprised 100 and 150 individuals respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It seems "A and B" is equal to "two", then the plural noun should be used.
But I think if we replace the word of "or" with "and", then the singular noun should be used.